# Pre-valuation of the company

Tags: investing, small-business, stock-valuation

I am planning to start a company, but it's just an idea with no revenues.  Hence, if I approach angel investors

- 1) What should be the pre- and post-valuation of the company after investors are ready to invest?
- 2) How much equity stake should I give to the investor?

Here are the financial facts I have calculated:

```
Funds required for 2 years of business = $1.7 M 

Y1 CAPEX + OPEX = -$0.8 M
Y1 Revenue      =  $1.8 M

Y2 CAPEX + OPEX = -$2.1 M
Y2 Revenue      =  $5.5 M
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but isn't *any* company that hasn't been started yet "just an idea with no revenues"?  Or are you saying that you don't know what your revenues are likely to be?  If the latter, then how did you calculate the revenue numbers at the bottom of your question?  Finally, please define your terms (CAPEX, OPEX, ...)

Comment: Its just an IDEA, We have no product in line hence no revenues. The numbers which I have mentioned is based on prediction - number of customers per year and total sale in that year. CAPEX - equipment related to business. OPEX-salaries, marketing, rent and all.

Comment: 1) What I am ting to understand is, how to calculate pre valuation of the company if its just an IDEA with no practical revenue. 2) If investors invest in our company, how much equity stake are they entitled to ask for, as we have not invested any money in the company from our side. Can they ask for 100% equity or they cannot go beyond 50%, as stakes will be required for next round of funding

Comment: 1) At this time, the value is whatever you could sell the idea for. Which in turn will be based on someone's best guess about future revenue. Which will be a matter of judgement and opinion. 2) They can ask whatever they want. You have to decide what you're willing to give them. This is a negotiation -- haggling -- not a standardized price, since the value *IS* a matter of opinion. Yes, I know, it would be easier if there were standard rules... but it's a matter of trying to guess that particular investor's rules.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the company is ill-defined until it actually has some assets and/or product. You give the investors whatever equity stakes you and they negotiate as appropriate for their investment based on how convinced they are by your plan and how badly you need their money.